# UWP: Sharing a storyboard

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

In WPF, I can create a storyboard as a page/control resource and then use it multiple times for controls within that page (or parent control)...

```
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource CorporateLogoBackgroundBrush}" views:MainWindowHelper.DragWindowOnMouseDown="True">

        <Grid.Resources>

            <Storyboard x:Key="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

        </Grid.Resources>

        <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0">

            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsNetworkConnectivityOk}" Value="false">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard">
                                    <StaticResource  ResourceKey="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard" />
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard"></StopStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>

            <TextBlock Text="LAN/WLAN" />

        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderThickness="0">

            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CorporateLogoBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SynchronisationClientService.IsActive}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SynchronisationClientService.IsRunning}" Value="false">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard">
                                    <StaticResource  ResourceKey="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard" />
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard"></StopStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>

            <TextBlock Text="SYNC" />

        </Border>

    </Grid>
```

However, I cannot find a way to do the same within UWP. Using the DataTrigger and BeginStoryboard in WPF automatically seems to associate the Storyboard.TargetName but in UWP I have to use the Interactions packages and trying to then associate the storyboard with the controls in the same manner errors as the storyboard is not associated with a control...

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource CorporateBackgroundBrush}">

    <Grid.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Key="FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>


    </Grid.Resources>


    <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0">

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsNetworkConnectivityOk}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="false">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard}" />
            </interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <TextBlock Text="LAN/WLAN" />

    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderThickness="0">

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsNetworkConnectivityOk}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="false">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashRedBackgroundStoryboard}" />
            </interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <TextBlock Text="SYNC" />

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

The only way I can find to do this in UWP is to have multiple identical Storyboards with each one having a reference to the control it will affect.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource CorporateBackgroundBrush}">

    <Grid.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Name="NetworkConnectivityStoryboard">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NetworkConnectivityBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Name="SynchronisationStatusStoryboard">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SynchronisationStatusBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

    </Grid.Resources>


    <Border x:Name="NetworkConnectivityBorder" Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0">

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsNetworkConnectivityOk}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="false">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource NetworkConnectivityStoryboard}" />
            </interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <TextBlock Text="LAN/WLAN" />

    </Border>

    <Border x:Name="SynchronisationStatusBorder" Grid.Column="5" BorderThickness="0">

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsSynchronisingk}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="false">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource SynchronisationStatusStoryboard}" />
            </interactionsCore:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <TextBlock Text="SYNC" />

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Is there a way that I can share a storyboard so that it can be used against multiple controls (in this particular instance, it is a status bar and certain elements need to flash when associated view model properties have a specific value. I cannot believe that I actually have to create multiple duplicate objects to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In UWP, a `Storyboard` can only animate **one** `Target` at a time. So technically, you can manually stop (i.e. `Storyboard.Stop`) it, change its `Target` property and start the animation (i.e. `Storyboard.Begin`) again.

But what if you want to animate two elements simultaneously? Then this approach won't work. This is why it makes sense to create a new `Storyboard` for each element that you want to animate.

---

Here's a solution using an *attached property* instead of static XAML. It's a bit of code to write, but once you have it setup, it's very easy to use (i.e. one line of XAML code) and works with almost any element too.

The idea is to create a `bool` property called `ShowFlashBackground` which can be attached to an element that has a `Background` property, such as `Border`, `Grid` or any `Control`.

Then, whenever this property is set to `true` (triggered by `IsNetworkConnectivityOk` for example), call an extension method `FlashElementBackground` to kick off the color animation.

**The Code**

```
public static class Util
{
    public static void SetShowFlashBackground(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ShowFlashBackgroundProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetShowFlashBackground(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(ShowFlashBackgroundProperty);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowFlashBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ShowFlashBackground", typeof(bool), typeof(Util), new PropertyMetadata(true, (s, e) =>
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                var self = (FrameworkElement)s;
                self.FlashElementBackground();

                // Rest the value back to false so the callback can be triggered again.
                SetShowFlashBackground(self, false);
            }
        }));

    public static void FlashElementBackground(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        string elementTypeName;

        switch (element)
        {
            case Border border:
                elementTypeName = "Border";
                if (border.Background == null) border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                break;
            case Panel panel:
                elementTypeName = "Panel";
                if (panel.Background == null) panel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                break;
            case Control control:
                elementTypeName = "Control";
                if (control.Background == null) control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                break;
            // More case statements can be added here to cover more scenarios...
            default:
                return;
        }

        var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        var keyFrame1 = new LinearColorKeyFrame { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)), Value = Colors.Transparent };
        var keyFrame2 = new LinearColorKeyFrame { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)), Value = Colors.Red };
        colorAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame1);
        colorAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame2);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, $"({elementTypeName}.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");

        var storyboard = new Storyboard
        {
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
            AutoReverse = true
        };
        storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
}
```

**The XAML**

```
<Border local:Util.ShowFlashBackground="{Binding IsNetworkConnectivityOk}">
    <TextBlock Text="LAN/WLAN" />
</Border>

<Border local:Util.ShowFlashBackground="{Binding IsSynchronisingOk}"
        Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock Text="SYNC" />
</Border>
```

Hope this helps!